# Excel 2010 doesnt auto calculate cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that is created from an SQL export. now the data that comes out is raw and needs excel to tidy it up. So the data tab is hidden and a front end tab has been created.

I then reference the cells with a formula similar to `=IF(VALUE(Sheet1!A2)=0,"",VALUE(Sheet1!A2))`

However the issue i am having is that the cells are not auto refreshing. I have to f2 and enter. Auto calculate is turned on and I have another sheet which is the same that works?

[image]

Comment: so like if your source data requeries and your Raw sheet has new data. Now where there was "0" there is now "2" but your formatted sheet still shows "" because it doesn't recognize the new "2"?

Comment: @Brad essentially yeah. Doesn't matter what i do, I can use =IF(Sheet1!C2=0,"",Sheet1!C2) or just =Sheet1!C2. it just doesn't refresh. But i go into the raw sheet and over type, it updated?

Comment: What happens when you hit `Formulas>Calculation>calculate Now`?

Comment: oh, I see your screen shot. when you say you hit `F2`+`Enter` is that in the formula cell or in the cell with the query? Because your query cells are formatted as text not numbers